# BeautifulSoup can't find div with specific class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

[image: Webpage HTML and my code]

So for some background I have been trying to learn web scraping to get some images for machine learning projects involving CNNs. I have been trying to scrape some images from a site (HTML code on the left, my code on the right) with no luck; my code ends up printing/returning an empty list. Is there something I am doing wrong?

For what it's worth, I tried finding other div tags that had an 'id' instead of a 'class' and that did work, but for some reason it can't find the ones I am looking for.

Edit:

```
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw'

response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'html.parser')

img_div = soup.findAll('div', {'class': "listing-cover-photo "})
print(img_div)
```

Edit 2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

listing = soup.select('.listing-cover-photo ')
for item in listing:
    print(item.select('img'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[<img alt="Off-White Off White Caravaggio Hoodie" src="https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:480,height:640,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/yX8vvvBsTaugadX0jssT"/>]
(...a few more of these...)
[<img alt="Off-White Off-White Arrows Hoodie Black" src="https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:480,height:640,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/9CMvJoQIRaqgtK0u9ov0"/>]
[]
[]
[]
[]
(...many more empty lists...)
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code? (as a snippet, not image, so we can run it)

Comment: Just did, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the code!  I see what the problem is. The web page is dynamically loading the product content, once the page has already loaded, as it's a React app... Maybe someone else on can help with the solution.. ? (Nice one @KunduK)

Comment: You need to see the XHR requests of the website. Actually, the front end consumes some APIs, and one of them contains what you need to scrape. Basically, you need to do post request to [https://mnrwefss2q-1.algolianet.com/1/indexes/Listing_by_followers_production](https://mnrwefss2q-1.algolianet.com/1/indexes/Listing_by_followers_production) with the same query that the website do. Then you can consume the API and get your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the website is loading the data using JavaScript.Try use Selenium and beautiful soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
items=soup.select(".listing-cover-photo ")
print(items)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue. Would you happen to know why the crawler only picks up the first 6 <img src=...> tags in each <div class="listing-cover-photo ">? I have been trying to get the remaining ones but I haven't been able to. Please see Edit 2 to better know what I am referring to.